# TimeZoneInfo DST vs Windows settings

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, dst

Does [TimeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.supportsdaylightsavingtime(v=vs.110).aspx) reflect the disabled/enabled status of "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" in Windows date  & time settings?

I'm trying to replicate those settings in a kiosk mode app where Windows is inaccessible for the user, and I've managed to get everything working including setting timezones with or without DST using tzutil, but while testing I noticed that some timezones DST settings (like Moscow) were not in sync with Windows.

We know that Russia got rid of DST a few years ago, so when I go to Windows and choose Moscow as my timezone, I see this:

[image: Adjust for DST automatically is off, because it's not supported?]

When starting my test console application (.NET 4.6.1), then fetch my current timezone from GetSystemTimeZones, I see that it actually does support DST:

[image: DST is supported]

If SupportsDaylightSavingTime is true, shouldn't the toggle switch be enabled in Windows settings?

I even went as far as testing by calling the Win32 function [GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724318(v=vs.85).aspx) to check whether DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled is true or false (although I'm not entirely sure if this reflects the settings in Windows either). I first tried with my real Timezone (Helsinki) and the results were:

When toggle swtich is on, *DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled* is **false**, but when the toggle is off, it becomes **true**. So I assumed that it probably does reflect it?

I tried with Russia, and the value for *DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled* is **false**, so daylight is enabled?

My Windows version is *10.0.17134 Build 17134* if that helps.

I'm really confused about this and would really appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: This is a very good question. I hope you find an answer.

Comment: Take a look at `.m_adjustmentRules`. You can see that there are no adjustment rules in effect after 2014.

Comment: Thanks glenebob, your comment lead me to the right answer. I should have read more about those adjustment rules!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason, as glenebob points out in his comment, is because there are no adjustment rules in effect after 2014 which is when Russia decided not to use DST anymore.

The Russian timezone does **support** DST, but only before 2014, so what I really had to do was to call the [TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getadjustmentrules(v=vs.110).aspx) to figure out whether DST is valid at this point in time or not.

The app I'm developing is also using UWP API's, which is actually missing this method, but that's a whole different problem...

I was on a wild goose chase there for a while... We live and learn...

**UPDATE:** I decided not to replicate Windows by checking the adjustment rules. Little value for too much effort and complexity. No thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  `TimeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime` will be true if there have *ever* been any adjustment rules whatsoever.  Regarding `DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled`,  it will only be true if the time zone has a transition in the *current* year and the user has specifically set the toggle switch off.  Also, if you want you can just check the registry for this value at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`

Comment: Oh, and in the image, it looks like you're matching on `StandardName`.  Don't do that - those get localized.  Use the `Id` property instead.  You can also just use `FindSystemTimeZoneById` for this instead of LINQ.  Additionally, don't use `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`.  Use `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.